# Run two or more Flink standalone job into same local machine

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I launched a standalonejob.sh command in this way:

```
./bin/standalone-job.sh start --job-classname org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.windowing.TopSpeedWindowing -r 8081
```

This is the output

```
Starting standalonejob daemon on host MSI.
```

If I go to `http://localhost:8081` I can reach Flink web dashboard.

Then, I launched another `standalone-job` command specifying port 3456 for web dashboard

```
./bin/standalone-job.sh start --job-classname org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.windowing.TopSpeedWindowing -r 3456
```

This is the output

```
[INFO] 1 instance(s) of standalonejob are already running on MSI.
Starting standalonejob daemon on host MSI.
```

I'm not able to reach `http://locahost:3456`

Is there a way to run, on different port, two instances of a standlone application cluster in Flink?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with the following command:

```
./bin/standalone-job.sh start --job-classname org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.windowing.TopSpeedWindowing -D jobmanager.rpc.port=8124 -D rest.bind-port=8082 -D rest.port=8082

./bin/taskmanager.sh start -D jobmanager.rpc.port=8124
```